# What's the proportion of hits for the tag suggestion system?

Tags: support, statistics, suggested-tags

I'm curious because I'm sure that askers (seasoned or not) depend greatly on the tag suggestions for tagging their questions, so I want to know the proportion of times that users select a tag from the suggestions, or ignore others and add their own.

If possible a breakdown per site would help. ;)